# Postgis function

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis

I have a table in postgres with some areas and geography data type (polygon format) and another table with products name and geographycal postion (point, 4326).
I tryed this query

```
“select st_intersects(schema1.tableA.geom1,schema2.tableB.geom2) from schema1.tableA inner join schema2.tableB on st_intersects(schema1.tableA.geom1,schema2.tableB.geom2)
```

Or this one:

```
”select prod_id from schema1.tableA inner join schema2.tableB on  st_intersects(schema1.tableA.geom1,schema2.tableB.geom2) where 
st_intersects(schema1.tableA.geom1,schema2.tableB.geom2).”
```

Both are running without any output and don’t stop.
The purpose is to get products that are in the specific areas.
Postgis extension is insterted and i could use it for other tasks on this db.

Comment: can you try with a limited dataset - like 100 rows from each table? It seems to me its not able to handle lots of records. are `geom1/2` are key columns ? Or at least indexed ?

Comment: Geom1 and 2 are indexed, table with products has some records so i used “limit 100” but same result, query is running..

Comment: thanks. how fast `select count(*) from schema1.tableA inner join schema2.tableB on geom1=geom2` works? if it takes time then join is the problem. but if it returns within few seconds then, st_intersects is the issue and you need to check how can you improve performance of this function - like passing few records/or some other parameters.

Comment: Amount of data seems to be, still running for 11 mins. 
I’m curious if the logic for selecting is ok, i will exercise it on small tables but i’ve never used gis functions and i didn’t find a video tutorial for postgis

Comment: Could you add the results of explain analyze to the question, along with table defs and number of records in each table?

Comment: Don't think you'll get any output anyway. You join on geom1 = geom2 but geom1 is a polygon and geom2 is a point so they are always different... Do the join just on the st_intersects...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second query can only be executed with a nested loop join, which will always be slow if both tables are large. The first query has the join condition twice, which will not make a difference, except that the query will be even slower.

On the bigger of the two tables you should create a GiST index on the geometry column, that will speed up processing as much as possible. If the polygons are large and have many points, that will make the query slow.

Comment: I have edited first query, i didn’t observe when i posted the question.